# Relation between delta and epsilon in a 2nd degree function

Tags: limits, inequality, epsilon-delta

I'm currently studying delta-epsilon limits and came across this problem that I can't understand the answer for. I've solved the problem multiple times and each time I get the same answer, shown below, that seems to make sense, but the given answer is completely different.
The problem is thus:
For each given $\epsilon$, find $\delta$ so that if $0 < |x-a| < \delta$ then $|f(x) - L| < \epsilon$

The limit is $\lim_{x \to 0} (x^2+3)=3$
Find the values of $\delta$ for the following three values of $\epsilon$:

1. $\epsilon = 2$
2. $\epsilon = 1$
3. $\epsilon = 0.3$

These are the steps I used to solve it:

1. By looking at the limit, $L$ is $3$ and $a$ is $0$.
2. Pick the first value for $\epsilon = 2$
3. The inequality is $|f(x) - L|<\epsilon$
4. The inequality filled in is $|x^2+3-3|<2$
5. Simplifying: $|x^2|<2$
6. The target form to determine $\delta$ is $|x-a|<\delta$
7. Thus $|x|<\delta$ as $a=0$
8. Converting line 5 to the form of line 7: $\sqrt {|x^2|} < \sqrt 2$
9. Thus $|x| < \sqrt 2$
10. Thus, given lines 7 and 9, $\delta = \sqrt 2$
11. Thus, the transform from a given $\epsilon$ to a given $\delta$ is $\delta=\sqrt \epsilon$
12. Solving for all three given values yields the answers $\delta = \sqrt 2$, $\delta = \sqrt 1 = 1$, and $\delta = \sqrt {0.3}$

I checked these answers against the solutions manual and the answer I got was completely different. The book states $$\delta=\frac{1}{5}\epsilon$$ and thus the correct answers are $\delta=0.4$, $\delta=0.2$, and $\delta=0.06$.

Who's right? If I'm wrong, where did I make an error in my steps? It seems to me that it is impossible to go from $x^2$ to $\frac{1}{5}$, so is it possible that the book's answer is incorrect?

Comment: Is your function correctly reproduced? The book answer would work somewhat better for $f(x)=x^2+3x$, under the a-priory restriction $δ\le 1$.

Comment: That's a good point, the book does list $f(x)=x^2+3$, I'm thinking it may have been a typo with the $x$ omitted.